# I am trying to create an object with data from FIrebase/Firestore for my REACT.js app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am following along on a Netflix Clone tutorial off of youtube that was put out about 6 months ago. At this stage in the project, we are using a extension called Stripe (used for secure online payments). What the tutorial is having me do is create a useEffect function that will query a Firebase/Firestore database for Stripe data. My Firebase/Firestore is already populated with Customers and Products. I think the issue is that any changes that Firebase/Firestore, REACT.js, etc. may have made since this tutorial came out is causing the useEffect function logic to break - it no longer seems to work. So let me show you what I've got going so far.

Here is my js file containing the code block:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import db, { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "../firebase";
import './PlansScreen.css';

function PlansScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const get = async () => {
            const q = query(collection(db, 'products'), where("active", "==", true));
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
            });

            setProducts(products);
        };


        get();
    }, [products]);

    console.log(products);

    return (
        <div className='plansScreen'>

        </div>
    )
}

export default PlansScreen
```

A few people helped me get this much, which does log data from the products collection in the console for me to see.

So this tells me that my Firebase connection is good. Here is my best interpretation of the structure of my Firestore Database:

```
Firestore-root
    |
    --- customers(collections)
    |           |
    |            --- customersId (document)               
    |                              |
    |                                --- email: "xxxxxxxxx"
    |                              |
    |                                --- stripeId: "xxxxxxxxx"
    |                              |
    |                                --- stripeLink: "xxxxxxxx" 
    |
    --- products(collections)
               |
               --- ProductId (document)
             
                      |
                      --- prices (collection)
                      |               |
                      |              --- priceId (document)
                      |                      |
                      |                     --- //Other price properties
                      |
                      |
                     --- //Other product properties
```

My useEffect function currently logs information from the products collection. I am not seeing anything from the prices collection.

I am following a tutorial that what put out on Youtube about 6 months ago but the logic the instructor used no longer seems to work. Here is what the instructor used:

```
function PlansScreen() {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

      db.collection("products")
      .where("active", "==", true)
      .get()
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
         const products = {};
         querySnapshot.forEach(async (productDoc) => {
           products[productDoc.id] = productDoc.data();
           const priceSnap = await productDoc.ref.collection
           ("prices").get();
           priceSnap.docs.forEach((price) => {
             products[productDoc.id].prices = {
             priceId; price.id,
             priceData: price.data(),
            };
            });
            });
            setProducts(products);
        });
    }, []);

    console.log(products);
```

Again this codeblock from the instructor does not seem to work anymore. I can sort of follow the logic of this block. The instructor wants the useEffect function to query the products collection and create a product object from each product document. Each product has pricing information so the useEffect function should also be adding data from the correct prices document to each product document.

I tried to be thorough with my explanation, hopefully this makes since and folks can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, you can remove 'products' from the dependency array and just update it inside the 'get' function:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const get = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'products'), where("active", "==", true));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    const products = [];

    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const product = doc.data();
      product.id = doc.id;
      product.prices = [];

      // Retrieve prices for this product
      doc.ref.collection('prices').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const price = doc.data();
          price.id = doc.id;
          product.prices.push(price);
        });

        products.push(product);
        setProducts(products);
      });
    });
  };

  get();
}, []);
```

The updated code initializes an empty array 'products'. For each product document in the 'products' collection, a product object is created and its pricing information is added. This product object is then added to the 'products' array. Once all products have been retrieved, the state variable 'products' is updated with this array.

**Note** that we're also adding the 'id' property to each product and price object to keep track of their document IDs.

Comment: I was getting an error saying that doc.ref.collection is not a function. I think a big part of my problem is that the tutorial was done when Firebase was SDK 8. Now I seem to have to write it in SDK 9 Modular. Refactoring it has been a big issue for me.